# question about PNG image format the lossless data compression

Tags: image, image-processing

If i take simple bitmap ( image without any compression ) and i compress it to PNG format 
and extract back to the original bitmap  -  do i get exactly the same image ?

Because the first step of the PNG compression is to do pre-compression =>  filtering ( prediction the current pixel according the the pixel before ) on the original bitmap - and that mean that after it the image will not be same if we will extract it after the compression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PNG uses lossless compression, so that the answer is *yes*, you will get the very same data after decompressing. The filtering stuff does not lose any information, it’s only a preprocessing stage to yield better compression ratios for some common sample patterns (like constant color lines or gradients).